# AVL tree inside an AVL tree in C++

Tags: c++, tree

I need to implement an AVL tree that every node will have an AVL tree. The concept is you get some links from e file e.g.

```
 ID   LinksTO
 0      0
 0      1
 0      2
 0      3
 1      0
 1      4
 1      6
```

etc.

I managed to implement an AVL tree that stores the ID's but we need to also store the Links of every ID in an AVL tree.
what's the best way to do it? have a node pointer that shows to the root of the AVL tree with the connections?

```
   class node 

  {   public:
        int ht;
        int conNum=0;
        int data;
        node *left,*right , *connections;


   };
```

or maybe AVL object in the class node? Don't know if that's even possible in C++

```
  {   public:
        int ht;
        int conNum=0;
        int data;
        node *left,*right;
        AVLtree connections;


   };
```

Assume that all the methods work fine from the AVL tree how is this possible?

```
   class AVL{

     node *root;
     int height(node*);
     node *rotate_right(node*);
     node *rotate_left(node*);
     node *RR(node*);
     node *LL(node*);
     node *LR(node *);
     node *RL(node *);
     int BF(node*);
public:
     AVL(){
         root=NULL;
     }

     node *insert(node*,int);
     node *delet(node*,int);
     void inorder(node*,ostream&);
```

};

Comment: Usually the compiler tells you what's syntactically possible. Did you have any particular problems with your approach?

Comment: Actually the problem is not syntactical. I don't know how and when to start building the sub trees for the connections . any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, what you are trying to achieve, just tell me if I understood it right: You want to make an AVL tree, which contains IDs and every node of this tree contains an AVL tree of IDs this node's ID links to?
Well, in my opinion you can do it on 2 ways:

1) Have an AVL tree of pointers to nodes this ID is linked to.
That means you have to add another pointer to node to every node of your tree.
That additional pointer would be linked to a tree that contains nodes containing pointers to nodes of your primary tree containing demanded linked ID.

2) Have an AVL tree of IDs this ID is linked to.
This would work ok, BUT you would have problems, when you would want to know linked IDs of a linked ID - you could not do it easily without searching through a whole tree.

In the end the first solution takes more time to add nodes, but offers you a nicer navigation. The second tree is faster to build, but a deep navigation is very expensive.

Comment: that's exactly what i am trying to achieve. because the IDs are around 300k and their links are not so much i think the navigations is not a big deal. ( an id should not  have  more than 100 links) . But in this case i will have to build around 300k avl trees  right? so i am really confused about what's the best way.